# TinyMCE outside Magento

Tags: magento, tinymce

I'm creating a mask for Magento, because the customer does not want employees to use directly magento. I need to change the descriptions of the products, can I use TinyMCE outside Magento? If I try to include it in my php file does not work

Thanks

Comment: Why you does not use the roles for the different admin accounts? Via roles you can manage the account accessibility to modules.

Comment: Admin roles would be the way to go here, instead of you ending up with creating custom platform just for updating product description. You should create new custom role and set specific permissions (to be able to only update products).